# Detect order of applications of transformations from ggplot object

Tags: r, ggplot2, inheritance, ggproto

These objects print the same but the objects themselves are different.

```r
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + xlim(1, 2) + geom_point() + geom_line()
p2 <- ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + geom_point() + xlim(1, 2) + geom_line()
p3 <- ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + xlim(1, 2)
length(waldo::compare(p1, p2))
#> [1] 229
length(waldo::compare(p1, p3))
#> [1] 190
```

I would like to understand from a ggplot object itself the order in which the transformations have been applied.

We can access the layers, scales etc using `p1$layers`, `p1$scales` etc, and we can find them there in order of appliance *by transformation type*, but I need to know the order overall.

`$layers` elements are equivalent between the plots above (as can be checked with `waldo::compare(p1$layers, p2$layers`), `$scales` element however differ due to environments found as attributes, function enclosures, or elements of other environments. This is the part I got stuck at.

A general answer is best, but an answer that will work "90% of the time" would be appreciated too. The general issue is not only about scales and layers but should include other transformations as well (coordinates, position, themes) as long as their position relative to objects of other types changes the output.

The output for the given examples might look like :

```
# 1st scale than 1st layer then 2nd layer
gg_order(p1)
#> scales layers layers 
#>      1      1      2

# 1st layer than 1st scale then 2nd layer
gg_order(p2)
#> layers scales layers 
#>      1      1      2

# 1st layer than 2nd layer then 1st scale
gg_order(p3)
#> layers layers scales 
#>      1      2      1
```

The number of transformations doesn't always match number of functions in the original code since a few functions apply several transformations, we can assume a one on one mapping here if it helps.

EDIT:

I have designed some tools that help navigating the waldo diffs, this might help:

```
devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/woof")
woof::woof_compare(p1, p2)
w <- woof::woof_compare(p1, p2)
w$scales$super$..env$env$self$super$..env
print(w$scales$super$..env$env$self$super$..env, substitute = TRUE)
```

Comment: it's a 500 point bounty question as soon as I can place it

Comment: Just curious ... why do you need this?

Comment: for {constructive} https://github.com/cynkra/constructive/

Answer (score 14):

This isn't an answer in the sense that this will help you further your goal, but perhaps it might help you scope out a different goal.

The reason that waldo is reporting differences between these plots, is because upon addition of every layer, the scales are cloned: the new scales become child environments of the old scales. The 'state' of the plot object, should thus depend on how many objects were added after the `xlim()` function, because this operation clones the scale that the function produces. The cloning happens in this line of source code:

https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/d7f22413efea3dd2a7c9effff05d4b2aa2c2d300/R/plot.R#L150

I believe this scale cloning is what lets waldo report differences, but I don't think the cloning is able to track any state in other parts of the plot, and therefore your goal might be unachievable.

The reason I believe so, is because one can do the following exercise. If you fork ggplot2, then comment out that particular line, those plot objects become identical (but won't render properly):

```r
library(ggplot2) # 3.4.2 from CRAN

p1 <- ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + xlim(1, 2) + geom_point() + geom_line()
p2 <- ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + geom_point() + xlim(1, 2) + geom_line()
p3 <- ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + xlim(1, 2)

length(waldo::compare(p1, p2))
#> [1] 224
length(waldo::compare(p1, p3))
#> [1] 190

# Now with local fork with that line commented out
# Path may differ on your machine
devtools::load_all("~/packages/ggplot2/")
#> ℹ Loading ggplot2

p1 <- ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + xlim(1, 2) + geom_point() + geom_line()
p2 <- ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + geom_point() + xlim(1, 2) + geom_line()
p3 <- ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + xlim(1, 2)

waldo::compare(p1, p2)
#> ✔ No differences
waldo::compare(p1, p3)
#> ✔ No differences
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

So unless one is really an R wizard and are able to wrangle out different states from these scale environments, I think the order of operations is irretrievable from the plot object alone.

I'd be happy to be proven wrong though!

Comment: Interesting thanks. Yes the link seems to be only from environments, let's do some R wizardry then :).

Comment: I just noticed you're a very regular contributor to ggplot2 so thanks so much for taking the time for this. Talking about scoping a different goal, do you think it's possible to scrub ggplot objects so we can test their equivalence ? In other words can we design a robust Waldo compare_proxy.ggplot method that would ignore the order ? That might need to be a new question but maybe you have quick insights on this ?

Comment: With a few specific exceptions, all the ggproto classes should be stateless factories for the most part, so you could skip checking a lot of their internals/methods, by simply checking their inheritance. The tricky bit would be to figure out these stateful exceptions. I'm not too familiar with the details of {waldo} so I'm unsure what exact needs are to be covered.

Answer (score 9):

**Edited at the end to discuss ggnewscale & ggh4x examples.**

I played around to see if one can "flatten" the multi-layered scales component of a regular ggplot object, and came up with the following:

```
flatten.scales <- function(gg) {
  
  # take stock how many different scales are contained within the top-level 
  # scale list, & sort their names alphabetically for consistency
  orig.scales <- gg[["scales"]]
  scale.count <- orig.scales$n()
  scale.aesthetics <- lapply(seq_len(scale.count),
                             function(i) orig.scales$scales[[i]]$aesthetics)
  names(scale.aesthetics) <- lapply(scale.aesthetics,
                                    function(x) x[[1]])
  scale.names.sorted <- sort(names(scale.aesthetics))

  # define a new empty scale list ggproto object
  new.scales <- ggplot2:::scales_list()

  # for each scale, traverse up its inheritance tree until we can't go any
  # higher without losing the function call -- i.e. any super's beyond this
  # point are inheritances defined in ggproto (e.g. ScaleContinuousPosition 
  # inherits from ScaleContinuous, which in turn inherits from Scale), not
  # inheritances created during cloning of scales within this ggplot object.
  # add that scale to the new scale list.
  for(i in seq_along(scale.names.sorted)) {
    scale.to.add <- orig.scales$get_scales(scale.names.sorted[[i]])
    while("super" %in% names(scale.to.add)) {
      scale.to.add1 <- scale.to.add$super()
      if(!is.null(scale.to.add1$call)) {
        scale.to.add <- scale.to.add1
      } else {
        break
      }
    }

    # added step to handle ggnewscale, as the top-level scale's aesthetic would
    # have lost the "XXX_new" format & lead to clash with another scale with
    # aesthetic name = "XXX". also keep use of the original guide (which includes
    # the renamed aesthetic under available_aes)
    if(!scale.names.sorted[[i]] %in% scale.to.add$aesthetics) {
      scale.to.add$aesthetics <- scale.names.sorted[[i]]
      scale.to.add$guide <- scale.guide
    }

    new.scales$add(scale.to.add)
  }
  
  gg[["scales"]] <- new.scales
  return(gg)
}
```

This won't return the order of the layers, but comparing two ggplot objects with flattened scales would allow one to ignore layer order differences, so that only other, presumably more serious differences are reported for the user's attention.

**Demonstration with a variation on the original example**

```
p1 <- ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + xlim(3, 26) + ylim(25, 100) + geom_point() + geom_line()
p2 <- ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + ylim(25, 100) + xlim(3, 26) + geom_point() + geom_line()
p3 <- ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + geom_point() + xlim(3, 26) + geom_line() + ylim(25, 100)
p4 <- ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + geom_point() + ylim(25, 100) + geom_line() + xlim(3, 26)

length(waldo::compare(p1, p2)) #  22
length(waldo::compare(p1, p3)) # 414
length(waldo::compare(p1, p4)) # 414
length(waldo::compare(p2, p3)) # 414
length(waldo::compare(p2, p4)) # 414
length(waldo::compare(p3, p4)) #  22

waldo::compare(flatten.scales(p1), flatten.scales(p2)) # No differences
waldo::compare(flatten.scales(p1), flatten.scales(p3)) # No differences
waldo::compare(flatten.scales(p1), flatten.scales(p4)) # No differences
waldo::compare(flatten.scales(p2), flatten.scales(p3)) # No differences
waldo::compare(flatten.scales(p2), flatten.scales(p4)) # No differences
waldo::compare(flatten.scales(p3), flatten.scales(p4)) # No differences

library(patchwork)
(p1 | p2 | p3 | p4) / (flatten.scales(p1) | flatten.scales(p2) | flatten.scales(p3) | flatten.scales(p4))
# confirm that the original plots & their variations with flattened scales all
# look identical to one another
```

**A more convoluted example with categorical & non-position scales, plus facets thrown in for good measure:**

```
p1 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(hwy, class, fill = class)) + 
  ylim(c("suv", "midsize", "compact")) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + 
  geom_jitter(width = 0.2) + 
  xlim(c(0, 35)) + 
  facet_wrap(vars(fl)) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2")

p2 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(hwy, class, fill = class)) +
  xlim(c(0, 35)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  facet_wrap(vars(fl)) + 
  ylim(c("suv", "midsize", "compact")) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.2) 

length(waldo::compare(p1, p2))                         # 623
waldo::compare(flatten.scales(p1), flatten.scales(p2)) # No differences
(p1 | p2) / (flatten.scales(p1) | flatten.scales(p2))  # Identical aside from random jittering
```

---

## ggnewscale

The ggnewscale package provides functions of the form `new_scale_xxx()` to allow subsequent layers to follow a different scale definition. (Somewhat confusingly, the original scale's aesthetic is named "XXX_new" while the new version is named "XXX".) I've updated the code for `flatten.scales` above by inserting a check for any difference in aesthetic name before adding each flattened scale to the scale list. If there's a difference (presumably due to ggnewscale, because so far I'm not aware of other packages that do this), the original scale's aesthetic name & guide are retained.

**Demonstration**

```
library(ggnewscale)
library(ggplot2)

# generate data
set.seed(123)
topography <- expand.grid(x = 1:nrow(volcano), y = 1:ncol(volcano))
topography$z <- c(volcano)
measurements <- data.frame(x = runif(30, 1, 80),
                           y = runif(30, 1, 60),
                           thing = rnorm(30))

p1 <- ggplot(mapping = aes(x, y)) +
  xlim(10, 70) +
  geom_contour(data = topography, aes(z = z, color = after_stat(level))) +
  scale_color_viridis_c(option = "D") +
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_point(data = measurements, size = 3, aes(color = thing)) +
  scale_color_viridis_c(option = "A") +
  labs(x = "HWY", y = "CLASS", colour = "Thing", colour_new = "Level") +
  ylim(10, 50)

p2 <- ggplot(mapping = aes(x, y)) +
  ylim(10, 50) +
  geom_contour(data = topography, aes(z = z, color = after_stat(level))) +
  scale_color_viridis_c(option = "D") +
  new_scale_color() +
  xlim(10, 70) +
  geom_point(data = measurements, size = 3, aes(color = thing)) +
  scale_color_viridis_c(option = "A") +
  labs(x = "HWY", y = "CLASS", colour = "Thing", colour_new = "Level")

length(waldo::compare(p1, p2))                         # 409
waldo::compare(flatten.scales(p1), flatten.scales(p2)) # No differences
(p1 | p2) / (flatten.scales(p1) | flatten.scales(p2))  # Identical
```

---

## ggh4x

The ggh4x package provides functions of the form `scale_xxx_multi()` to allow multiple scales to be mapped to colour / fill. Like the ggnewscale case, order of layers matter, because `scale_xxx_multi()` affects all earlier layers that make use of relevant aesthetic mappings, by making changes to their innards.

Hence, the situation is rather more complex because even after `flatten.scales()` scrubs through the scales, the layers component of the ggplot object contain remnants of the original scales present when `scale_xxx_multi()` took effect.

**Demonstration**

```
library(ggh4x)

p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point(aes(swidth = Sepal.Width),
             data = ~ subset(., Species == "setosa")) +
  geom_point(aes(pleng = Petal.Length),
             data = ~ subset(., Species == "versicolor")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Assorted measurements") +
  geom_point(aes(pwidth = Petal.Width),
             data = ~ subset(., Species == "virginica")) +
  facet_wrap(~ Species, scales = "free_x") + 
  scale_colour_multi(
    aesthetics = c("swidth", "pleng", "pwidth"),
    colours = list(c("black", "green"), c("gray",  "red"), c("white", "blue")),
    guide = list(guide_colourbar(barheight = unit(35, "pt")))
  )

p2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length))  +
  geom_point(aes(swidth = Sepal.Width),
             data = ~ subset(., Species == "setosa")) +
  geom_point(aes(pleng = Petal.Length),
             data = ~ subset(., Species == "versicolor")) +
  geom_point(aes(pwidth = Petal.Width),
             data = ~ subset(., Species == "virginica")) +
  facet_wrap(~ Species, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_colour_multi(
    aesthetics = c("swidth", "pleng", "pwidth"),
    colours = list(c("black", "green"), c("gray",  "red"), c("white", "blue")),
    guide = list(guide_colourbar(barheight = unit(35, "pt")))
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Assorted measurements")

length(waldo::compare(p1, p2)) # 876
for(i in seq_along(p1)) {
  cat(i, "(", names(p1)[i], ") :")
  res <- waldo::compare(p1[[i]], p2[[i]])
  if(length(res) == 0) {
    cat("No diff")
  } else {
    cat(length(res))
  }
  cat("\n")
}
# 1 ( data ) :No diff
# 2 ( layers ) :232
# 3 ( scales ) :644
# 4 ( mapping ) :No diff
# 5 ( theme ) :No diff
# 6 ( coordinates ) :No diff
# 7 ( facet ) :No diff
# 8 ( plot_env ) :No diff
# 9 ( labels ) :No diff
# p1 & p2 differ in layers & scales

p1.flattened <- flatten.scales(p1)
p2.flattened <- flatten.scales(p2)
for(i in seq_along(p1)) {
  cat(i, "(", names(p1)[i], ") :")
  res <- waldo::compare(p1.flattened[[i]], p2.flattened[[i]])
  if(length(res) == 0) {
    cat("No diff")
  } else {
    cat(length(res))
  }
  cat("\n")
}
# 1 ( data ) :No diff
# 2 ( layers ) :232
# 3 ( scales ) :No diff
# 4 ( mapping ) :No diff
# 5 ( theme ) :No diff
# 6 ( coordinates ) :No diff
# 7 ( facet ) :No diff
# 8 ( plot_env ) :No diff
# 9 ( labels ) :No diff
# flattened versions of p1 & p2 still differ in layers

cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p1.flattened, p2, p2.flattened, nrow = 2)
# but at least everything still looks identical
# (cowplot used to arrange the plots, as patchwork complained)
```

If we peer into `waldo::compare(p1.flattened[["layers"]], p2.flattened[["layers"]])` (or equivalently `waldo::compare(p1[["layers"]], p2[["layers"]])`, since the function didn't do anything with the layers component), we get various messages such as:

```
`parent.env(environment(old[[1]]$geom$draw_key))$.GenericCallEnv$p$scales$scales` is length 4
`parent.env(environment(new[[1]]$geom$draw_key))$.GenericCallEnv$p$scales$scales` is length 3

...

`parent.env(environment(old[[1]]$geom$draw_key))$.GenericCallEnv$p$scales$scales[[1]]` is length 2
`parent.env(environment(new[[1]]$geom$draw_key))$.GenericCallEnv$p$scales$scales[[1]]` is length 19

(omitted)
```

While it's probably possible to write another function that scrubs through the environments to remove the offending elements (which appears to be copies of the original plot with scales in a particular order), I hesitate to do so for two reasons:

1. Based on my understanding, these environments are not unique to each ggplot object. I.e. suppose we have a function `scrub.layers()` that performs the task, whatever happens in `p1.new = scrub.layers(p1)` will affect the original `p1`, since they reference the same environments.
2. I'm not that good with environments & haven't managed to come up with a viable solution after two days of trying. (I did manage to increase my exposure to a fascinating variety of error messages though :P).

That said, `waldo::compare` does have an option to ignore comparisons within environments of functions, if that's a viable option for you:

```
length(waldo::compare(p1, p2)) # 876
length(waldo::compare(flatten.scales(p1), flatten.scales(p2))) # 232
length(waldo::compare(p1, p2, ignore_function_env = TRUE)) # 77
length(waldo::compare(flatten.scales(p1), flatten.scales(p2), ignore_function_env = TRUE)) # 0
```

**TL;DR:** If it's okay to *not* compare environments, `flatten.scales` should work for ggh4x's `scale_xxx_multi` -- subject to further stress tests based on actual use cases, that is.

Comment: Thanks! That looks great and like something I can use. I'll be AFK today but I believe if one defines `compare_proxy.ggplot <- function(x, path) list(object = flatten.scales(x), path = path)`, one should see no difference when calling `waldo::compare()`.

Comment: And the fact the scrubbed objects are printable and identical makes it believable. I'll have to stress test this a bit. One hard corner case would be to see how it deals with `ggnewscale::` stuff, that's really ok if it doesn't at this point though.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't work well with `ggnewscale` out of the box. In addition, while the multi scales in `gg4hx` can be flattened to identical state, there's some lingering effect surrounding the geom layers' `draw_key` functions, which I haven't quite figured out. Will look at it again when it's daytime on my end.

Comment: FYI by keeping count in the while loop and a bit of manipulation I could reproduce my desired output for the given examples. I'm happy to add the code to your answer once it's cleaned up, or self answer separately if you prefer.

Comment: @moodymudskipper Have updated my answer with a (long-winded) discussion on how it applies to the two packages. Pls feel free to edit :)